# WPF Control Template Not Changing Based on Dependency Property Bound Value

Tags: wpf, templates, controls, datatemplate, controltemplate

I have tasked with creating a new layout control to be used for our Windows application-wide and there should be two different layouts; which one is shown on a particular Windows would be based on a dependency property.  I have never done anything quite like this, but based on my research it seems like a `Control` should be used.  To learn this I tried creating the new `Control` which would show either a `TextBox` or `Label` based on a property value.  I created by class:

```cs
public class DetailsLayout : Control
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty OverlayProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Overlay", typeof(bool), typeof(DetailsLayout),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(true));

    public bool Overlay
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(OverlayProperty); }
        set
        {
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Overlay));
            SetValue(OverlayProperty, value);
        }
    }

    static DetailsLayout()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(DetailsLayout), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(DetailsLayout)));
    }

    public DetailsLayout()
    {
        DefaultStyleKey = typeof(DetailsLayout);
    }
```

In `MainWindow` I have:

```xml
<layout:DetailsLayout Overlay="False">       
</layout:DetailsLayout>
```

For the testing, if `Overlay = True` I want to show the `TextBox` and if `Overlay = False` it should show the label.  To accomplish this, I tried several things.  First I tried creating two `ControlTemplate`'s:

```xml
<ControlTemplate x:Key="OverlayTemplate">
    <TextBox Text="This is the default (TRUE) layout (OVERLAY) with a textbox."/>
</ControlTemplate>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="PushTemplate">
    <Label Content="This is the optional (FALSE) layout (PUSH) with a label."/>
</ControlTemplate>
```

And then use these via the style definition:

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type layout:DetailsLayout}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
       <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type layout:DetailsLayout}">
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding}">
                    <ContentControl.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                            <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource OverlayTemplate}"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Overlay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False">
                                    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource PushTemplate}"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ContentControl.Style>
                </ContentControl>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

I also attempted to get it working using `DataTrigger`'s; one with a default value and one where both values are specified:

**Both Values**

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type layout:DetailsLayout}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Overlay}" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type layout:DetailsLayout}">
                        <TextBox Text="This is the default (TRUE) layout (OVERLAY) with a textbox."/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Overlay}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type layout:DetailsLayout}">
                        <Label Content="This is the optional (FALSE) layout (PUSH) with a label."/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

**With Default**

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type layout:DetailsLayout}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type layout:DetailsLayout}">
                 <TextBox Text="This is the default layout (OVERLAY) with a textbox."/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Overlay}" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type layout:DetailsLayout}">
                        <Label Content="This is the optional layout (PUSH) with a label."/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
             </Setter>
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

The goal is just to get the correct template selected when the control is loaded.  So one window may use the control like `<layout:DetailsLayout Overlay="True" />` and other window would use `<layout:DetailsLayout Overlay="False" />` and in the first window a `TextBox` would be shown and in the second window a `Label` would be shown.  But once shown, it would not need to be changed as the `Overlay` value is specified only in the XAML (no control will be changing this value at runtime).

Lastly, I also tried using `DataTemplate`'s instead of `ControlTemplate`'s like so:

```xml
<DataTemplate x:Key="OverlayTemplate">
    <TextBox Text="This is the default (TRUE) layout (OVERLAY) with a textbox."/>
</ControlTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="PushTemplate">
    <Label Content="This is the optional (FALSE) layout (PUSH) with a label."/>
</ControlTemplate>
```

but that did not work either.  Any suggestions/samples on how to get the simple sample working would be greatly appreciated as I can't find any other suggestions other than the ones I have already tried.  Thank you in advanced.

Comment: Implementing INotifyPropertyChanged for dependency properties is pointless. They do already provide their own notification mechanism. Remove it, and update your question.

Comment: Besides that, `Binding="{Binding Overlay}"` needs a declaration of a source object: `Binding="{Binding Overlay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`.

Comment: @Clemens I was 99.99999% sure that the INotifyPropertyChanged wasn't doing anything for this, but I was seriously at the end of trying everything so I figured I would just try it.  But the adding the RelativeSource worked perfectly!  Thank you SO much.

Comment: I did this to experiment with changing the templates.  In actual use, the layout will be more complicated with a header section, a main body, and a sliding draw that will have ```ContentPresenter``` so the user will be able to add whatever controls they want as this is specifically just a layout control.  It was developed because this is how all our screens are laid out and everyone keeps coding it differently, so I wanted to create a control that can be used instead of, say, a grid or stackpanel and will implement out layout and sliding draw section (in case this makes any difference)

Answer (score 0):

Big thank you to Clemens for helping solve this issue.  The solution was changing the binding expression in the `DataTrigger` from `Binding={Binding Overlay}` to `Binding={Binding Overlay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}`.